# grok pattern to get the whole text without considering space

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, grok

I am trying to grok a message text with my grok pattern if i pass the sample data without space my grok pattern works fine but if there is any space in between text it fetch only the first word before space and after space it ignores.

In my case i need to get the whole text with out considering space.
I have given my grok pattern and sample data below

**sample data:**

```
"CSIC_agentId:bo peng"
```

**Grok pattern:**

```
CSIC_agentId:%{NOTSPACE:apm_agentId.agentId}
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "apm_agentId": {
    "agentId": "bo"
  }
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
{
  "apm_agentId": {
    "agentId": "bo peng"
  }
}
```

Could some one help me to resolve this issue.? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the grok pattern that will match your sample input log:

```
CSIC_agentId:%{GREEDYDATA:apm_agentId}
```

Please find below the screenshot of the output
[image]